# How do you print the inorder traversal of a BST?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, computer-science, graph-algorithm

“Give a non recursive algorithm that performs an inorder tree walk”.

Wouldn’t this just be a standard depth first search? None of the non-recursive solutions I saw online for this problem did anything that really resembled DFS (even though they all used stacks)…is my reasoning incorrect?

Here is my pseudocode:

`public inOrder(Node root):
     create new Stack -> s
     create new boolean set -> visited
     s.push(root)
     while(!s.isEmpty()):
          currNode = s.pop() 
          print(currNode)
          if(!visited.contains(currNode)):
               visited.add(currNode)
               if(currNode.right != null):
                    s.push(currNode.right)
               if(currNode.left != null):
                    s.push(currNode.left)`

Comment: You can format your code by selecting the text and clicking on the `{ }` button in the editor.

Comment: I'd expect the non-recursive solution should print the same as recursive  `bst_print(head) { if (head)  { bst_print(head.left); print(head.value); bst_print(head.right); }}`.  Agree?

Answer (score 1):

DFS is not necessarily in-order, though in-order is DFS. See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search). Any recursive function can be implemented non-recursively with a stack (since recursion uses a stack).

As you can see by comparing your code with the pre-, in-, and post-order traversals in the wikipedia article, your code traversal is pre-order because it prints the parent node before the children. In order to make this implementation an in-order traversal, the left node must be printed first. This can be done by

1. checking if `currNode.left` is not null and has not been visited
2. if (1) is true, push `currNode` and `currNode.left`
3. if (1) is false, add `currNode` to the visited set, print `currNode`, and push `currNode.right` if it exists.